# Images and mysterious numbers. Replace the question mark

Tags: cipher

Below we have some images and numbers. Try replace the question mark.

(▭, ∆):(1147125)::(, ):(198916)::(, ):(152314)::(, ):( ? )

Hint:

> Separate the numbers somehow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer could be

> 5120

The reason is the following:

> In the word "eat" each letter is replaced by its alphanumeric value. This is the fragment which is common in "heat" and "meat" . The others being: rectangle, triangle ("angle"), maybe friendship/worship, spaceship ("ship") and town, crown ("own").